# I don´t get to see my mistake. Why do I get this error? raise RequestsJSONDecodeError

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

.........................
.......................
......................
When I execute, python py_client/details.py, I get:

```
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
 0)
```

What´s going wrong here?

detail.py

```
import requests

endpoint = "http://localhost:8000/api/products/1"

get_response = requests.get(endpoint)

print(get_response.text)
```

this is urls.product

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views 

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', views.ProductDetailAPIview.as_view()),
    
    path('', views.ProductCreateAPIview.as_view()),

] 

I am getting error Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
It doesn´t work in the browser either. It says: Page not found (404)
```

this is urls.cfehome

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include("new_api.urls")),
    path('/api/products/', include("products.urls"))
    ]
```

this is my view in the app products

```
from rest_framework import generics

from .models import Product
from .serializers import Productserializers


class ProductDetailAPIview(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Productserializers




class ProductCreateAPIview(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Productserializers
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `print(get_response.text)` try:

```
print(get_response.json())
```

Comment: I just tried it but I´m getting the same error